# no prompt when connected to SSH using agent forwarding

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm currently working from home and need to connect to a production server. The security policy at work does not permit VPN clients to connect to production instances. As such, I figured I could configure agent forwarding through the development server (which I can access), since this is allowed.

To do this, I first enabled agent forwarding for the dev server:

1. I added `ForwardAgent yes` to `~/.ssh/config` for the development server entry on my computer
2. I ran `eval 'ssh-agent'` to start the ssh agent
3. I added my ssh key to the agent using `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
4. I connected to the dev server using `ssh -A <devserver>`
5. On the dev server, I attempted to connect to the production server using `ssh -T me@<prodserver>`

After this, I was able to run commands on the production server. However, I never see the actual bash prompt.

[image: Missing bash prompt]

Is there something I can do to ensure the prompt shows up?

[image]

Comment: If your company does not allow access to production machines from VPN clients, why are you trying to access them then? If you need it to do work, ask your manager to change the policy.

Comment: the security guy says I should use the dev server to get access to the prod server. I'm not sure how this increases security (if at all) but that's the policy I have to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last step, run `ssh` without the `-T` option:

```
-T      Disable pseudo-terminal allocation.
```

Using the `-T` option actually disables allocating a TTY, which in turn makes that you don't get a shell.

```
mtak@rubiks:~/bla(develop)$ ssh gen1
THIS IS A PRIVATE COMPUTER SYSTEM. Unauthorized access prohibited.
You have mail.
Last login: Tue Mar 10 10:45:25 2020 from vpn-int-2.int.mtak.nl
mtak@gen1:~$ logout
Connection to gen1 closed.

mtak@rubiks:~/bla(develop)$ ssh -T gen1
THIS IS A PRIVATE COMPUTER SYSTEM. Unauthorized access prohibited.
You have mail.
date
ma mrt 16 16:12:53 CET 2020
```

Answer (score 1):

> I attempted to connect to the production server using `ssh -T me@<prodserver>`

You're not getting a prompt because using the `-T` option **told ssh to disable terminal mode** (tty allocation).

The presence of a tty is how all programs determine whether they're being run interactively (i.e. attached to terminal/keyboard) or whether they're being fed commands from a file or a pipe. In the latter case i.e. "batch" mode, it is normal for shells to disable all prompting; tools such as 'ls' lose their fancy formatting and colorized output; and so on.

Comment: Thanks! I can't ssh into the prod server without `-T` though, is there another flag I can use instead?

Comment: If you can't ssh without -T, then it implies the server was (mis)configured in such a way that it's unable to assign you a tty (or the shell is misconfigured in such a way that it exits if it has a tty...), and that directly returns you back to the same problem no matter what.

Comment: You could probably force the shell itself to show a prompt (try using `ssh me@server bash -i`), but that will not help with any other terminal-dependent features.